# Pasar un VARBINARY a INT como un listado en sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una base de datos en la que una de sus columnas es de tipo de dato VARBINARY(MAX) y al momento de hacer la consulta me trae lo datos asi

```
0x7D7D7D7E7E80818182828384848483828281817F7F7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7
```

en una sola columna un solo registro.

existe alguna forma para pasar este solo registro y dividirlo de tal manera que quede de esta manera

```
128
129
129
130
130
131
132
138
138
137
137
136
136
135
135
```

....................
 pero todo hacerlo con sql

Comment: ¿Qué datos lleva el varbinary?

Comment: es una señal que esta en hexadecimal asi como la que puse de ejemplo  0x7D7D7D7E7E808181................

Comment: ¿Cómo sabrias que el numero es 128 y no 1281? o sea cómo lo separias? Es una trama que respeta siempre la misma estructura?

Comment: 0x7D 0x7D 0x7D 0x7E 0x7E 0x80 0x81 0x81

Comment: ¿Inicialmente cuál fue la lógica para guardar el valor hexadecimal como binario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aca te paso un código que te puede servir..

```
declare @Trama varchar(max) =     '0x7D7D7D7E7E80818182828384848483828281817F7F7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7D7'
declare @NumeroIndividual varchar(2) = ''

IF OBJECT_ID ('TEMPDB.DBO.#TramaSeparada') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #TramaSeparada

CREATE TABLE #TramaSeparada
(
   ValorNumerico int
)

SET @Trama = Substring(@trama,3,len(@trama))

WHILE LEN(@Trama) > 0
BEGIN
    begin
    SET @NumeroIndividual = Left(@Trama, 2)
    Insert into #TramaSeparada select CAST( CONVERT(VARBINARY,'0x'+RIGHT('00000000'+REPLACE(@NumeroIndividual,'x',''),8),1) AS INT) 
    SET @Trama = Substring(@trama,3,len(@trama))
END
END

select * from #TramaSeparada
```

Que te devuelve algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y como puedo hacerlo con una consulta y no con un valor fijo ??

Comment: el valor de `@trama` podes llenarlo como vos quieras. Podes asignarle el valor de una consulta siempre que sea uno solo. Si son varios, deberías hacer un bucle. Por ejemplo `Set @Trama varchar(max) = (Select....)

Answer (score 0):

No tiene sentido convertirlo a un string dividido. Quien le entiende a un binario ? es mas útil en binario, en fin, allí va la receta

Primero convertirlo a string y de allí hacer un ciclo por cada 3 caracteres y le añades el enter 'char(10)'

algo así

```
declare @b varbinary(max)
set @b = 0x5468697320697320612074657374A1

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @b, 1)
declare @letext varchar(MAX)
set @letext = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @b, 1)

declare @length int
declare @parsedstring varchar(MAX)
declare @token varchar(3)
declare @startpoint int

set @length = len(@letext)
set @startpoint = 1

while(@length > 3)
begin
  set @token = substring(@letext, @startpoint, 3)
  set @parsedstring = coalesce(@parsedstring + '|' + @token, @token)
  set @startpoint = @startpoint + 3
  set @length = @length - 3
end

set @token = substring(@letext, @startpoint, 3)
set @parsedstring = @parsedstring + '|' + @token

select @parsedstring
```

Basta con que lo pases a una función de sql y listo

Comment: Este código no sirve para lo que pide el OP. Los valores son Hexadecimales no binarios. Por lo que con dos caracteres formas un decimal de 3 dígitos. Por ejemplo 7D7 es 2007.